# Tetris Rotation Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making Tetris, and I'm having issues getting the rotations working for a group of blocks. My groups of blocks consist of 4 block sprites that are children to an empty gameobject.

[image]

I move/rotate the blocks by updating the position/rotation of the parent object's transform, validating that the new position is within the grid, and then updating the individual child blocks.

```
this.transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0);
if (IsValidGridPos())
    UpdateGrid();

this.transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
if (IsValidGridPos())
    UpdateGrid();
```

For each group, I have a center point where I want the group to move/rotate around. The image below shows where my center points are for each group.

[image]

This works as intended for most of the groups, except for the straight-line and square group. Because both groups center points are not in the middle of a child block, it throws off the blocks position inside the 2D array I use to hold all blocks positions.

Is there a better way to handle a group's movement/rotation?

Comment: You could/should just make the groups for the line and box smaller to fit their actual size? Or move them to center of the group?

Comment: Just as a side note. I could be wrong but the way I remember it is that cyan(line), green and red (s/z) shapes have only 2 positions/orientations. They didn't have 2 horizontal/vertical positions offset by 1.

Comment: your approach is correct and should work. Are you sure that you dont use a cast to int at the wrong place of something like that?. Note that the center position might not be on the grid, so its position cannot be cast to int

Comment: @Nikaas I believe you are right.

Comment: I'm going to debug the 2D array once I get out of work. I'll post another comment with what I find.

Answer (score 0):

For Group I and O, their center points are located either in between it's child blocks or on the side of the blocks. This led to my spawning script to place the group's center point in the correct position but not their child blocks.

***The positions for Group_I and it's children's positions.***

[image]

To fix this issue, I created a new script that will move the Group's transform position 0.5 in the x and y axis as soon as the Group is created.

```
const float DISTANCE = 0.5f;
void Awake()
{
    // Moves the center point of a Group over so it's 
    // child blocks can align correctly with the game grid.
    this.transform.position += new Vector3(DISTANCE, DISTANCE);    
}
```

If anyone has a better solution, please feel free to let me know. Thanks to everyone who commented on my question.